# How can I add environment variables to an application running on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I generated a .war from a web application, and I'm trying to deploy it using vanilla Tomcat 7 (no Eclipse or anything else).

And here is my problem: the application relies upon environment variables to connect to things and then launch.

In CLI, I do set them via `APP_ENV=deploy ./run.sh`: can I set them anywhere in Tomcat? It doesn't seem possible from the web interface and config files.

Answer (score 5):

create a file named bin/setenv.sh - this will be sourced if it's there.

In there, provide the settings:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsome.property=some.value -Xmx1024m"
```

(only samples, you get the concept)

This is obviously for system properties, but the same should work with environment variables. I'm not aware of techniques to set them at runtime through some interface. But then, at runtime, you don't need to rely on environment variables but can handle any other configuration technique.

If you want to go through server.xml and web.xml, you can also use [tomcat-environment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Environment_Entries) configurations. (That chapter might provide other means to configure your application through tomcat as well)

Comment: it may save some nerves if you define environment variables in setenv.sh using export, like `export FOO=bar` (or `set FOO=bar` for windows).